# Android: App get restarted when user tried to enable chrome on settings page and pressed back button

Tags: android

I have a login, dashboard and terms and conditions page. After user logged in and I am displaying a dashboard screen with a button that opens terms and condition page. After coming to terms and conditions page, If user clicked Agree button I am opening chrome custom tabs to load a page.

Login -> Dashboard -> Terms and conditions -> Chrome custom tabs

On Terms and conditions page, on Agree button action, I am checking if user has chrome enabled, if not, I am opening settings page for the user to enable Chrome.

Problem: If user enables chrome on settings page and clicks back button, app is getting restarted and takes user back to login page.

Expected: Taking user back to dashboard page. But the actual result: App restarted and user gets back to login page

So my question is,
1.Is it expected for an app to get restarted whenever you enable chrome on settings?
2. If not how can i prevent my app from being restarted and simply take the user back to dashboard page?

```
if (isChromeCustomEnabled()) {
//Create an intent builder
String url = "https://google.com";
Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
CustomTabsIntent.Builder intentBuilder = new CustomTabsIntent.Builder();
CustomTabsIntent customTabsIntent = intentBuilder.build();
customTabsIntent.intent.setPackage(CHROME_PACKAGE);
customTabsIntent.launchUrl(TermsAndConditionsActivity.this, uri);
} 
else {
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
if (null != intent.setData(Uri.fromParts("package", "com.android.chrome", null))) {
  startActivityForResult(intent, 9);
  finish(); //I am finishing terms and conditions page here in order to come back to dashboard page
} 
}
```